# Rails CSV export to server instead of download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a form which when submitted takes all the input and generates a csv. I am using CSV.open in my model so that the file is sent to the server. However, even with this, there is a separate CSV file with a random CSV code that is generated. It does not contain any form details, however, it would be ideal if no CSV is downloaded at all. I just want to CSV to get uploaded to the server.

Model:

```
def csv
    attributes = %w{ first_name last_name }
    CSV.open("#{Rails.root}/public/#{self.first_name}.csv", "wb") do |csv|
        csv << attributes

        csv << [ self.first_name, self.last_name ]
    end
end
```

controller:

```
def method
  if conditions
    student = Student.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Success"}
      format.csv { send_data student.csv } 
    end
  else
    redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Declined"
  end
end
```

Please let me know whats wrong

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "separate CSV file with a random CSV code"?

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your full controller method.  However, `format.csv { send_data @student.csv }` is going to return a CSV to the browser.  You may want to render a different template.

Comment: A random CSV code as in like this #<CSV:0x007fcf7dbb6f08>

A csv is generated with this code and a csv with the actual input fields is sent to the server. Apologies if this is unclear.

Controller method:
`code
  def method
   if conditions
    student = Student.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Success"}
        format.csv { send_data student.csv }
      end
   else
    redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Declined"
   end
  end
`

Does this make sense?

Comment: Hey, I solved this. Thanks for your tip @TomAranda. Instead of calling format.csv, I passed the input details to the model and then called the open method for CSV which sent my csv to the server without downloading anything. Now my question is: Is it safe to do this? Since I am sending form details from my controller to model. Apologies if my questions are very naive.

Comment: One might say that the main purpose of a Rails app is to send form data to the model.  There  are safe ways to do it an unsafe ways to do it and unsafe ways to do it.  From what I can tell, you are creating a CSV and storing it in a folder on your server.  The danger comes from what you do with that CSV.  If that CSV contains malicious data, it could affect you depending on how you process it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your input ! I appreciate your help with this.